# State and ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple asp.net MVC 3 app with a page that has a form and an @Html.Hidden("hiddenField"). I am modifying the value of the hiddenField through JavaScript, when the form submits depending on the input I might have to return to the same View, but when I do the hidden field is pre populated with the values from the post.

How is this possible. It is my understanding that the programmer is fully responsible to maintain state with asp.net MVC. or is the Helper class automatically setting the value base on the request values?

Comment: It's apparently saving your hidden field to the database when you Submit (which is expected behavior, if you architected your application correctly). Then, when you return to the same view, the view is prepopulated with the previous values from the database.

Comment: There is no DB saving here and I'm not returning to the default view. I'm returning View() from the action that handles the HttpPost

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because when binding HTML helpers first use values in ModelState and after that in the model. So if you intend to modify a value inside the POST controller action that was posted you need to remove it from the model state. Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove("SomePropertyThatYouWantToModify");
    model.SomePropertyThatYouWantToModify = "some new value";
    return View(model);
}
```

Now your `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SomePropertyThatYouWantToModify)` will render the new value.

And for the completeness of my answer if you are using ViewData (but I really hope you aren't):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
{
    ModelState.Remove("SomePropertyThatYouWantToModify");
    ViewData["SomePropertyThatYouWantToModify"] = "some new value";
    return View();
}
```

and in your view `@Html.Hidden("SomePropertyThatYouWantToModify")` should render the new value.

Comment: spent 3 hours on trying to find out why it is not working in my example, taken out ModelState.Clear() from it, i knew it was there for a reason :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a model binder issue. If the hidden field generated by your `@Html.Hidden("hiddenField")` call doesn't have a name that the model binder can recognize as your model's property, it's going to be using the value populated by whatever process you have that builds the model (assuming you're building the model and only updated the fields posted by your view).

Based on your example, your model's property name would have to be `hiddenField` exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue in how **MVC 3** is handling this. If I show my model value as in `<h3>QuestionType: @Model.QuestionType</h3>`  it shows the new value. But in the hidden field it has the old value. `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.QuestionType);`

I am not updating the old model value and returning it. I am creating an entirely new model and returning that in my post method as in return `View(getNewModel())`

Darin's answer above does solve my issue. I just use `ModelState.Clear()` before returning the view and everything seems to work fine.